# Step 4 in one page checkout for magento not working in IE 9

Tags: magento, internet-explorer-9

I already tried forcing compatibility mode to IE8 and it does not seem to work.  Seems like steps 1-3 work fine but then when I got to select credit card info, nothing responds to my clicks... the cardtype does not drop down a selection and none of the inputs are selectable.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this problem and forcing IE8 compatibility [as described in my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311882/magento-sites-in-ie9-prototype-bugs/5313553#5313553) fixed it. Of note, the position of the `meta` tag at the top of the `head` is important.

The other way around it, apparently, is to have more than one payment method. (There have been some reports that the bug only manifests itself on IE 9 when there is only one payment method available.)

Comment: I already read that post and I forced IE8 with both the meta tag and htaccess and it did nothing.  I would try the second payment method but not my site... client's and they only use one

Comment: Do you have caching enabled? I forget this all the time. You might verify that the meta tag is actually appearing in the output. Depending on the age of the Magento installation, you may have better luck with the "IE=EmulateIE7" mode. (The problem is caused by Magento using an outdated version of Prototype, one that has IE-specific hacks that break in the now standards-compliant IE9.)

Comment: yeah I tried both (not at the same time) and verified it both times but still no dice

Answer (score 0):

I actually just dealt with this for a friend of mine.  You have to make sure that the quirks mode tag is the very first tag following the header tag.

Browse to the following location:

app/design/frontend/default/your template/template/page/

Unless you've heavily modified the magento install the template that contains the checkout should be in that folder.  It's most likely the 2column-right.phtml or 2column-left.phtml file. (I put one in all the code files to force every page on the site to use IE8 quirks mode just to be safe).  Your header should look exactly like this:

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

**Also, when you are done don't forget to flush the cache in the admin section.  It 'should' work if you put it in the right place.**

Comment: using magento 1.4.... tried the IE-8 and emulate 7 meta tags... again... flushed cache... bout to go crazy

Comment: So when you browse to the checkout page, and click view source do you actually see the quirks mode tag as the very first tag following the header.  Just to verify that it's there?

Comment: IE 9 allows you to click the broken page icon in the address bar to force IE8 mode.  If you do that... does it fix it?  I realize that's only a temporary fix for a single session but I'm just trying to help troubleshoot.

Comment: yeah if the tag is removed the button appears... but it does not resolve the issue

Comment: Hmmm, that's a problem then.  Clicking that button fixed our problem wich is why adding the quirks mode tag also worked.  If that doesn't help you then something in your java-script is not playing the same game our site is.  Magento does teach patience doesn't it??

Comment: ok i lied... if I remove the tag... and press the button in the bar it works!!  however, when I force it with the tag it still does not work

Comment: And the broken page icon does disappear when you force quirks mode indicating that "supposedly" it has followed the tag's advice, huh... well, i'm running out of ideas for you

Comment: ok weird... I did this again by adding the same tag back for forcing ie 8.... this time it the compatibility mode button did not disappear, but it stays highlighted and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem with 1.5.1.0. Any luck with finding a solution, Adam?

The X-UA-Compatible fix hasn't made a difference, although the broken page compatibility mode icon has gone from the address bar.

Edit: Nevermind. I found [this fix](http://magebase.com/magento-articles/ie9-issues-with-magento-fix-workaround/comment-page-1/#comment-1046), thank Jebus. I thought I'd never fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in the head of your template. Will cure any problems with Magento and IE9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```