# Magento - Internet Explorer Cart Issues

Tags: session, magento, cookies, cart

I'm on Magento 1.4.1 and get regular calls (2-3 per week) from customers that they are unable to add products to their cart. The symptoms are the same for customers: All use IE (7 or 8, most commonly). When they attempt to add to cart, they are taken to an empty cart page. Repeated attempts do not resolve the issue. I have not been able to verify, and the only version of IE I have access to is 9. I would dismiss this as user error except for:

1. Generally lower-than expected conversion rate on my site (explainable if large % of IE customers are unable to transact).
2. Consistency of symptoms: Browser and version, action that is failing

I assume this is an issue with setting the session or cookie (but could totally be wrong and am open to other suggested causes). If it is a cookie issue, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341068/magento-frontend-session-cookie) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985892/step-4-in-one-page-checkout-for-magento-not-working-in-ie-9) post from Stack Overflow which give a little information, but not a solid idea of how to go about confirming it is a cookie or session issue.

Can someone suggest the best way to get started with diagnosis?

Answer (score 2):

setting cookie lifetime to 86400 as [recomended here](http://ka.lpe.sh/2011/07/09/magento-cant-loginadd-items-in-chrome-and-ie/) did the trick for me.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl. Trying hard to think of any downside to this.

Comment: Actually, my cookie expires are set to 21600 so that is probably not the issue. However, will try 86400 and see if this helps.

Comment: is there a reason you're still with 1.4.1? It may not solve this particular problem (it may though :-)) but I'd still recomend you to upgrade. Also, take Anton's suggestion into account and try to recreate this error yourself, it will be easier to solve.

Comment: I've tried to re-create the error several times. I have access to IE 9 and IE 6, and have not been able to replicate the error (always my first step before posting). I've tried some browser emulators for IE 7 and 8, without success in replicating the error either. I also have a very good Magento engineer who has not been able to replicate the error on IE 7 or 8 after a couple hours of testing.

Comment: Oh, on Magento I'm developing a new theme for the site and that is being developed on 1.5.1 and we're currently testing 1.5.1 with my extensions. I should be on that newer version in a month. I'm planning to move to 1.6.x in February.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 bundles development tools (from settings menu) and this allow you to emulate ie7 - ie9 versions in all compatibility modes.

If you are getting blank pages then there is always a php error behind this and you can see those errors from your server php error log.

Comment: We're not getting blank pages (that would actually be easier to troubleshoot). Just the standard empty cart page with no errors reported. I've checked the server logs for errors during the timeframe of the error, and none to be found.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with items disappearing from the cart, it only happened in a store that was using a subdirectory of the main domain, and only with ie9 and older ie's. We also had varnish running on the frontend, and magento 1.4.1.1

e.g.
www.example.com  = main store

www.example.com/sub/  = secondary store

After adding items to the secondary store basket in ie9, you could then go to the main store and add more items, return to the basket page and all was well then if you went to another secondary store product and added another item to the basket, then visited the basket page all previous items had gone, but the one just added was there.

We found we could consistently reproduce this by visiting a secondary store product page, adding to the basket, visit the basket - item is there, return to the product page, return to the basket, item has gone. It turned out to be a bad background image url in the stylesheet, and the rule was only used by the product page template, this 404 error was enough to cause ie9 and older ie's to lose the session and start a new one.

ie10 and 11, chrome, firefox and safari didn't have this problem at all, so if you're getting intermittent customer reports of baskets suddenly being empty, check the whole site for 404's, all it can take is one missing image to lose the session for ie9 and older ie's.