# Magento purchase order validation IE7

Tags: php, magento, internet-explorer-7

Having problems with validation on the built in  PO checkout form specifically with IE7. IE7 will allow the user to continue to the next step without anything entered into the PO text feild. All other browsers tested and use prototype.js validation (IE8+, FF, Chrome, Safari)

I have ensured the text feild has validation class "input-text" and "required-entry"

The following has been attempted:

Adding meta tag forcing IE compatibility, this fix suggested by others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311882/magento-sites-in-ie9-prototype-bugs) only works for similar bugs in IE9

```
 <meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=8″ />
```

Modifing .htaccess file (similar to fix above)

```
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
```

Creating a secondary validation using jQuery. This also worked for all other browsers other than IE7 and lower

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".poinput").focusout(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){
        alert('Enter a valid instore PO'); 
        }
    });
});
```

During the checkout process if no data is entered in Name/Address/Phone# etc fields the Magneto validation does work in IE7 however which has me stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have mixed quotes in `<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=8″ />` (Word quotes)

Comment: Yes apologies, that was just formatting from my copy/paste efforts. I used the formatting in the link provided in the question.

Comment: Must be a Javascript error showing up in IE7